# Node.js - TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I'm facing an issue in nodejs when I try to execute and script file that I've created for testing purposes.
I need to test it in my localhost (Windows OS) before I can implement webservice in webserver (Linux OS).

I installed jsdom and jquery right after installing nodejs but still having the following message error:

> **TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined**

This happened after I tried to rum this JS script named `index.js`:

```
// Carrega a biblioteca HTTP do Node.js.
var http = require('http');
var $ = require('jquery')(require("jsdom").jsdom().parentWindow);
//var $ = require('jquery');

// Cria um serviço web para tratar a requisição de resposta da mensagem Hello World.
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
// Define os parâmetros de cabeçalho de resposta.

// usage  
response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
// Escreve uma mensagem de resposta do servidor.
response.write('<html><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html>');

// usage
$("body").append("<div>TEST</div>");

// Envia uma resposta para o cliente
response.end();
});

// Define a porta e IP que serviço executado a aplicação.
server.listen(3000);
// Imprime mensagem no terminal do servidor.
console.log('Servidor Node.js em execução.');
```

If It comment the following line, it gonna work without recognize jquery functions:

```
var $ = require('jquery')(require("jsdom").jsdom().parentWindow);
```

I need to use jquery with nodejs, but I've tried to google this problem but no success.

Following bellow, there is an image in Command prompt when I rum `node index.js`:

[image]

Is there anything else should I try to make node.js running successfully with jquery?

If I need to post any further information, please, advise me.

**UPDATE**

I tried to rum the same script inside Node.js path from other Programmer's Computer. We faced another `TypeError` problem:

[image]

Comment: What version of JSDOM do you have?

Comment: I installed and cmd prompt showed me this: `jsdom@4.0.0 node_modules\jsdom`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **The latest versions of jsdom require Node.js v8 or newer. (Versions of jsdom below v12 still work with Node.js v6, but are unsupported.)™**

[From JSDOM's NPM page.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom)

Try making sure you install JSDOM 3.x.

```
npm install jsdom@3.x
```

Comment: No way. I'll try to install jsdom 3.x  and see if I can rum this script.

Comment: @Scimonster Error: Cannot find module 'jsdom' =/

Comment: Throw new error, jquery require a window with a document =[

Comment: @ErasmoOliveira Um, odd.

Comment: @Scimonster I got the same problem here =(